# Create SQL user-defined function in ColdFusion with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, user-defined-functions

I'm doing queries in which I want to extract the left-most **n** characters from a string that has been stripped of all leading and following spaces. An example is:

```
Select SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(somefield)), 0, @n) AS mydata
FROM sometable
```

It's the only way I can figure to do it on a SQL Server.

I've never written a UDF before, but I think if I was just working on a SQL Server, I could create a user-defined function such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfLeftTrimmed
(
    @inputString nvarchar(50),
    @n int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(@n)
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@inputString)), 0, @n);
END
```

I could then do something like:

```
Select udfLeftTrimmed(somefield,6) AS mydata
FROM sometable
```

which is at least a little easier to read and understand.

The question is, how do I create the UDF in ColdFusion? All my searches for SQL user-defined function in ColdFusion just gave me how to create ColdFusion functions.

Comment: You can simple create the MSSQL function by executing the `CREATE FUNCTION ...` statement in ColdFusion using the `<cfquery>` tag.

Comment: What would I put as the datasource? It won't accept empty or no datasource -- causes error. Also, would I call it by the cfquery name, or the function name?

Comment: You'd use the datasource that points to the DB you want to create the function in. And I don't really think you get how `<cfquery>` works when you ask your second question. All it is is a mechanism to pass SQL statements to a DB. The `name` attribute one gives the tag when doing a `SELECT` query is so when the recordset is returned by the DB, CF has a variable name to use to reference it. You would not even use a `name` attribute when passing a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement, as it doesn't return anything useful. Once the function is created *in the DB* then you can use it in your SQL..

Comment: ... statements within your `<cfquery>` tag. Bear in mind the function is withn the DB, and the SQL statements are run within the DB too. The SQL statement in the `<cfquery>` tag is just a meaningless string as far as CF is concerned; just something to pass to the DB driver. CF does not "execute" the SQL.

Comment: Thanks. You have helped me understand better what `<cfquery>` does. Unfortunately, I'm working with multiple databases, which means I would have to create the UDF for each one. The payoff is now getting very small...

Comment: Why? A UDF is only created once.  That said, a udf in one database can also be used from another database on the same server, IF the user account has access to both.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is nothing special or "dynamic" about your UDF you really don't need to create it in CF.  You should just create it using MSSQL Manager. UDFs in SQL are like stored procedures. Once created they are a part of the DB/Schema.  so create once, use as many times as you like (as @leigh has mentioned).

Keep in mind that using a SQL udf in SQL usually requires the user prepend as in:

```
<cfquery...>
Select dbo.udfLeftTrimmed(somefield,6) AS mydata
FROM sometable
</cfquery>
```

Note the "dbo.udf..."  that dbo is important and may be why your subsequent try is failing - besides getting a duplicate UDF error by now. :)

NOTE:

To follow up on your comments and Leighs, you can create your UDF in a DB accessible to your user then access it as dbo.dbname.function ... as inthe following code:

```
<cfquery...>
 Select dbo.myspecialDatabase.udfLeftTrimmed(somefield,6) AS mydata
 FROM sometable
</cfquery>
```

Then you need only create it one time.

Comment: @abalter - Yes, *SQL* UDF's are really a dbms concept. (Totally different than CFML UDF's).  It just so happens you can create SQL udf's using cfquery, but ... they are still db objects. Therefore, you typically create them via SSMS, not CF. Hence why your searches probably did not turn up many results. *Note the "dbo.udf..."* Yep, where "dbo" is the schema name. For more details see [User Defined Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx).